# How to replace all fields of a column with just the integer values from string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a CSV file that I loaded into R with a column labeled "How_Long_Delayed". In this column, there are values entered in a variety of ways, but I want to replace each entry in the column with just the integer value from the field. For example, it may be entered as "15 minutes","16-30 Min", or "20 MIN". I only want the column to contain "15" or "16-30" Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions removing everything but digits and "-", e.g.:

```
DT$How_Long_Delayed <- gsub("([0-9-]*)(.*)","\\1",DT$How_Long_Delayed)
```